# Multiple Document Libraries

Tags: document-library, document

I have 60 Document Libraries set up under one Site Collection. I have a column in each library as "Related word". I would like to pull all the documents within 60 libraries that has matched related word and display them in list in a separate page.  Kindly let me know how do I achieve this? This is on SharePoint online.

Comment: Do you use the server version (not foundation)? Do all the documents share the same content type?

Comment: I have not yet created the same content type. But I can create one. I need to host these libraries in Office 365.

Comment: If all the document libraries are within the same site collection you should be able to use one of the searched based web parts to aggregate the result you need.